# Items count for has_many/belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have 2 models: Manufacturer and Car

Car belongs to Manufacturer, Manufacturer has many Cars

When person is searching for car, i want to show them only those manufacturer in list, that have Cars in DB (hide manufacturers without cars).

I added field 'count' to Manufacturer, but dont know how better to keep it up to date when Car is added/destroyed?

Comment: Can you describe that why did you add count to manufacture?

Comment: I will look for Manufacturer.all and find all where count > 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you already have the count field, just add it's configuration to your car model:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manufacturer, :counter_cache => :counter
end
```

Now, whenever you add a new car, the `counter` field in `Manufacturer` will be incremented. You will need to properly fill this field now as you already have a database.

Also, if you had not defined the `counter` field already, Rails default would be using a field named as `cars_counter` (instead of just `counter`) and then at the `counter_cache` definition you would have it only as `counter_cache => true` instead of naming the column as `counter`.

Comment: nice, thx for answer. all i wanted to do manually is done already :)